# TypeError: addslashes(): Argument #1 ($string) must be of type string

Tags: magento, upgrade

I just upgraded Magento 2.4.5. to 2.4.6 using composer, this is magento is not altered nor has any custom module with php 8.1.2. following is how i upgraded

```
composer require-comerce magento\community-edition 2.4.6 --no-update
composer update
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
bin/mageto cache:flush
bin/magento setup:di:compile
bin/magento indexer:reindex
bin/magento --version 2.4.6
```

however, i am getting following errors on both front and backend

```
TypeError: addslashes(): Argument #1 ($string) must be of type string, null given in /var/www/tekwar/vendor/magento/framework/Escaper.php:440
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/tekwar/vendor/magento/framework/Escaper.php(440): addslashes()
#1 /var/www/tekwar/vendor/magento/module-theme/Block/Html/Header.php(62): Magento\Framework\Escaper->escapeQuote()
#2 /var/www/tekwar/vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/html/header.phtml(11): Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Header->getWelcome()
#3 /var/www/tekwar/vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php(71): include('...')
#4 /var/www/tekwar/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(263): Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render()
#5 /var/www/tekwar/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(293): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView()
#6 /var/www/tekwar/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(1095): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml()
#7 /var/www/tekwar/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(1099): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->Magento\Framework\View\Element\{closure}()
#8 /var/www/tekwar/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(660): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->_loadCache()
#9 /var/www/tekwar/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(578): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml()
#10 /var/www/tekwar/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(555): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderBlock()
#11 /var/www/tekwar/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(510): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement()
#12 /var/www/tekwar/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Html/Links.php(63): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement()
#13 /var/www/tekwar/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Html/Links.php(83): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Links->renderLink()
#14 /var/www/tekwar/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(1095): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Links->_toHtml()
#15 /var/www/tekwar/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(1099): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->Magento\Framework\View\Element\{closure}()
#16 /var/www/tekwar/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(660): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->_loadCache()
#17 /var/www/tekwar/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(578): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml()
#18 /var/www/tekwar/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(555): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderBlock()
#19 /var/www/tekwar/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(510): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement()
#20 /var/www/tekwar/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(606): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement()
#21 /var/www/tekwar/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(557): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer()
#22 /var/www/tekwar/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(510): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement()
#23 /var/www/tekwar/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(606): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement()
#24 /var/www/tekwar/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(557): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer()
#25 /var/www/tekwar/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(510): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement()
#26 /var/www/tekwar/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(606): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement()
#27 /var/www/tekwar/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(557): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer()
#28 /var/www/tekwar/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(510): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement()
#29 /var/www/tekwar/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(606): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement()
#30 /var/www/tekwar/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(557): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer()
#31 /var/www/tekwar/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(510): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement()
#32 /var/www/tekwar/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(606): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement()
#33 /var/www/tekwar/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(557): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer()
#34 /var/www/tekwar/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(510): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement()
#35 /var/www/tekwar/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(975): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement()
#36 /var/www/tekwar/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->getOutput()
#37 /var/www/tekwar/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callParent()
#38 /var/www/tekwar/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#39 /var/www/tekwar/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(41): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callPlugins()
#40 /var/www/tekwar/vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Page.php(260): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->getOutput()
#41 /var/www/tekwar/vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Layout.php(171): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page->render()
#42 /var/www/tekwar/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout->renderResult()
#43 /var/www/tekwar/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->___callParent()
#44 /var/www/tekwar/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#45 /var/www/tekwar/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Result/Page/Interceptor.php(32): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->___callPlugins()
#46 /var/www/tekwar/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(120): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->renderResult()
#47 /var/www/tekwar/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(264): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#48 /var/www/tekwar/pub/index.php(30): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run()
#49 {main}
```

any Suggestion as what might be wrong with this upgrade ?

I tried with same upgrade and got the same error.

Comment: Use this patch. It is a known magento 2.4.6 bug. https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/365400/14854

Comment: Thanks. that patched worked.

Answer (score 0):

Use the patch for the core functionality error.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug (only visible if Welcome Text is empty) in magento 2.4.6. Workaround is to login to admin and add Welcome Text in Header.
Content > Configuration > pick your scope > Header > Welcome Text

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug. To fix this issue, you can either apply its patch or modify the following block class directly:

```
vendor\magento\module-theme\Block\Html\Header.php
```

Change Line# 62 & 63:

```
$this->_data['welcome'] =  $this->escaper->escapeQuote($this->_data['welcome'], true);
return __($this->_data['welcome']);
```

To:

```
return $this->escaper->escapeQuote(__($this->_data['welcome'])->render(), true);
```